# ¿Qué hacer con respuestas del tipo "He probado tu código pero funciona"?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123451/problema-al-llamar-funci%C3%B3n-jquery) se ha respondido con:

> He probado tu código pero funciona

Creo que sería más un comentario que una respuesta porque no contribuye nada.

Estos tipos de respuestas lo he visto ya varias veces... entonces mi pregunta es:

¿Qué hacer?

- ¿Reportar?
- ¿Votar en contra?
- ¿Ignorar y tomar un té?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a la respuesta de Asier o a una que ya fue eliminada?

Comment: @Rubén - Si.. no hay otra... pero es un ejemplo de varios que ya he visto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entiendo que el problema en estos casos es que la pregunta plantea un problema que *no se puede reproducir*, al menos por parte de quien respondió.

Por tanto, lo pertinente sería añadir un comentario en la respuesta sugiriendo que vote para cerrarla con ese motivo, en lugar de publicar una respuesta que no aporta nada a la hora de resolver el problema planteado.

> - ¿Reportar?

No creo que haga falta. Los reportes son señales enviadas a los moderadores para que hagan cosas que nosotros no podemos hacer. Pero no es el caso, pues el abanico de opciones que tenemos es grande.

> - ¿Votar en contra?

Dado que, además, la respuesta no es especialmente útil, no vería descabellado darle un voto negativo, si bien yo personalmente no lo haría si se trata de una respuesta bien escrita y con buena fe.

> - ¿Ignorar y tomar un té?

Un té siempre sienta bien :)

Comment: Pues sí un té ahora con el frío que hace vendría suuuper bien... :) ... me he dado cuenta que el OP de la pregunta tiene varias preguntas similares y ha tenido también respuestas similares del tipo: _He probado tu código pero funciona_ ... no crees que los moderadores tendrían que hacer algo al respecto? [link del otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123395/problema-al-tomar-valores-de-una-fila-en-una-tabla-jquery)

Comment: @aldanux Esa es otra pregunta completamente diferente: qué hacer con un caso serial. Personalmente le dejaría un comentario hablando de esto, votaría para cerrar todas las preguntas que no se pueden reproducir (dejando un comentario, generalmente con un link a un fiddle que lo demuestre)... Y, recién si no se obtuviera un buen resultado con esto, y veo que se está volviendo en contra del sitio, ahí plantearía ese caso en particular en Meta o levantaría un flag para que se encargue un moderador (dependiendo de si me interesa o no que el resto de la comunidad opine).

Comment: @aldanux los moderadores tienen poderes extras, pero no creo que sea necesario involucrarlos en esto a menos que tome un cariz ingestionable. Lo que parece más práctico es lo que comenta Mariano: dejar al OP un comentario explicando que no se puede reproducir (enlazando a un fiddle si se tienen ganas y tiempo), votar para cerrar con ese motivo y tira millas. Si el sistema detecta que muchas de sus preguntas se están cerrando, acabará bloqueándolo.

Comment: Perfecto... pues entonces ha quedado bastante claro... actuar sobre la pregunta y tomar un té sobre la respuesta... :) Gracias una vez más a los dos - @Mariano

Answer (score 3):

La única respuesta al momento a la pregunta de referida es más amplia que sólo decir "He probado tu código pero funciona", en particular adapta el código y lo agrega a un stack snippet. La redacción se puede mejorar y tal vez ampliar la descripción de lo realizado.

Lo que procede sería, si no tienen ningún sentido el aporte o no se entiende, votarlo negativo. Si se tienen recomendaciones para mejorar la publicación, o dudas, dejar un comentario.

Comment: En primer lugar.. repito es un ejemplo, de varios que he visto, de respuesta... Además (para mi) no es más amplia la respuesta por el simple hecho de reproducir el código que tiene el OP y decir que no hay fallos en ese código... un comentario es en mi opinión suficiente y si no es reproducible cerrar la pregunta... entonces para que me entiendas... la pregunta va en general y no al enlace que he proporcionado... que hacer a las respuestas tipo: _He probado tu código pero funciona_

Comment: @aldanux el segundo párrafo en mi respuesta se puede aplicar de forma general al tipo de respuesta a  las que se refiere la pregunta.